How to compile a library having alpine linux target inside ubuntu
I'm having a library need to be used inside the alpine linux based docker container, I pre-build the library in my ubuntu machine and copied into the container, but error throws on pthread_mutex_clocklock undefined ref. I expect this is due to target mismatch, So, I need to compile my library having target alpine linux inside the ubuntu.
I tried musl-gcc with architecture x86_64-linux-musl but it throws the same error only.
I didn't find any way to cross-build the target.

You're using Ubuntu to build a library for Alpine? Try using Alpine to build a library for Alpine. From your Ubuntu machine, you can create an Alpine container to build from using Docker, a VM, or LXC
